# Image Pyramids - Dealing with Arbitrary Dimensions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

Looking at the Image Pyramids tutorial I see the following note:

Notice that it is important that the input image can be divided by a factor of two (in both dimensions). Otherwise, an error will be shown.

I was wondering, How can Image Pyramid can be built for arbitrary image size and keep the "Reproduction" exact (Up to round off errors).

Taking image size of 101 x 101, After the first "Downsample" step using 1:2:101 an image size of 51 x 51 is yielded.
Yet after another iteration 26 x 26 image is yielded, so how can we handle both odd and even sizes.

I'd be happy for a MATLAB code dealing with the "Upsample" / "Downsample" procedure for any size.

Comment: @rayryeng, I'm after those "some work" things. I had the idea to replicate pixels to the next power of 2 on each dimension, but that would be "Wrong" for large images.

Answer (score 0):

For downsampling the better approach would be to delete the last row & column from the image, thus a 101×101 generates 50×50. Though it may be a matter of taste, I think is better to ignore real information than to introduce bogus information.

For upsampling, I'm afraid what you ask is impossible. Let's say you have a 200×200 pixel image; can you tell from its size that is was downsampled from a 400×400 pixel image, or from 401×401 pixel image? Both would give the same result.

Comment: So, how can you achieve the best technique to ensure reconstruction as close as possible to the original image?

Comment: @Drazick Define "best", please.

Comment: Namely, the reconstruction will be as close as possible to the input.

Comment: @Drazick Sorry, but what you suggest as criterion does not apply in every case. My last part of the answer suggests a mathematical impossibility (unless the original size of the picture is made up of powers of 2). Which means, the decision you must take for the size of the upsampled picture is not mathematically correct, but heuristically "correct". Which means, you may try different strategies to make the blown-up picture look nice compared to the original, for a number of cases, but you'll never know if it will work with a completely new picture that you never tried before. Ergo, not "best".

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. If you go by sampling mathematics then you want the image to be a power of 2 + 1. Though you can do some tricks to work with power of 2. Now, think you have something which knows how to deal with Even -> You can reconstruct perfectly at least one "Step". Now, you know how to do one step for Odd. Summing it up, all you need to know is a flag for each level was it "Odd" or "Even". It can be done, I just thought someone has more elegant way.

Comment: @Drazic I agree with what you just said, but I think we talk about different things. You say that you'd use some flags that give hints about even/odd cases for every step of up-sampling. But that means that you have already the original picture. The point of up-sampling is to try to blow up a picture, giving us the sensation of "detail", *without knowing what original "target" would be*. If we know what the target would be, you may just as well use it directly, no need for up-sampling.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some techniques where they resize the dimensions of the original image to be **even, before** they subsample the image. This odd and even stuff is unfortunately unavoidable as you have already seen, so you'd have to do some work by yourself before you pass it to an image decomposition routine. That way there is no ambiguity when constructing your image pyramid. When you're done, you can crop out those portions of the original image that you don't want. Another technique would be to eliminate the row and column to ensure that they're both even as well.

As such, all you'd have to do is extend your image's dimensions to ensure that each dimension is even.  In other words, you'd do something like this:

```
im = imread('...'); %// Place image here
rows = size(im,1);
cols = size(im,2);
imResize = imresize(im, [rows + mod(rows,2), cols + mod(cols,2)], 'bilinear');
```

This basically reads in an image and the dimensions (rows and columns).  After, it resizes the image to ensure that the dimensions (rows and columns) are even.  This is done by checking to see if the values are odd by using `mod`.  If any of the dimensions are odd, the output would be `1` and you would just tack this on as the output dimensions.

Also, you can simply crop out the last row or column if they're odd too by doing:

```
im = imread('...'); % // Place image here
rows = size(im,1);
cols = size(im,2);
imResize = im(1:rows-mod(rows,2), 1:cols-mod(cols,2), :);
```

The `mod` here is used in the same way to crop out what you don't need.  If any of the dimensions are odd, simply subtract 1 so that we eliminate either the last row or last column if needed.

---

As CST-Link has already stated, upsampling from an image that has odd dimensions already would be impossible to reconstruct the original image dimensions as that precision in order to get those original rows and columns back if they were odd were already lost.